# Prove that if $R$ is an Integral Domain then $S$ is an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ be a subring of $R$. Prove that if $R$ is an Integral Domain then $S$ is an Integral Domain.

I know that an ID is a commutative ring when for $a,b \in R$ if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ $b=0$ so I know I've got to show that if this property is true for a ring that it is also true for a subring but im not sure how.

Comment: I assume this is homework?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are in $S$ and $xy=0$, then $\dots$. There are some additional details that I cannot do, since I don't know whether in your course integral domains have a multiplicative unit, and how subring is defined.

Comment: It's not polite to give commands "Prove that...", especially given the lack of effort.

Comment: @ChrisEagle An ID is a commutative ring when for $a,b \in R$ if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ $b=0$ so I know I've got to show that if this property is true for a ring that it is also true for a subring but im not sure how.

Comment: @Lepidopterist If I require a proof then I have to write prove that, I am currently trying to do this myself but I thought I could get help so I am putting effort in. Therefore it's not 'polite' to accuse someone of something without knowing all of the facts

Comment: @Adam: hint: elements of a subring are elements of the ring. If a,b are in S, ab=0, you need to show a =0 or b =0, and you know a,b are also in R.From here, how do you do next to show a =0 or b =0?

Comment: The fact is your question to the MSE community was a command to the community to "prove xyz". And on top of that you gave no attempt (prior to your edit) to show what you've done or explain your understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Lepidopterist It wasn't a command I was stating what I needed to do. Go troll somewhere else.

Comment: @LongMai As $a,b\in R$ then $ab=0\in R$ so either $a=0$ or $b=0$. Is this enough to complete the proof?

Comment: @Adam Yes, of course.

Comment: @Adam: what Lepidopterist was trying to say is that it is more polite to ask "how would I do this" rather than saying "Do this". To some, this may seem a small thing, but it really grates on others.

Comment: @robjohn Fair enough but to be honest I don't see the difference and I have no idea why he felt the need to comment on the question. If he didn't like it he could have just not answered it. There was no need to start having a go at me

Comment: @Adam: There are people who feel both ways. Just know that this is not necessarily between you and Lepidopterist; this complaint happens quite often, actually.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the statement is not true as given. An integral domain is necessarily a nonzero/nontrivial ring, so the statement does not hold for $S=(0_R)$. However, the statement is true for all nonzero subrings of $R$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose, for the sake of a contradiction, that $ S $ is not an ID. By definition this means that $\exists x,y\in S$ s.t. $xy=0$ but $x,y\not= 0$. But since $S\subset R \implies x,y\in R$  , which means $xy=0 \implies x=0$ or $y=0$. (This follows along the lines of Long Mai...)

Comment: I have one doubt.$2Z$ is subbing of $Z$ but $2Z$ is not integral domain though $Z$ is integral domain.This is a contradiction right?