# Confusion in Gallian Books ( ABstract algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement is True /false

A  subring of an integral domain  is an integral  domain

my answer : see the  image  here  there  are  2 definition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kFsl.png)

According to gallian  books  Its   is false   But according to maths online  it is True

Im confusion   which  definition  i have to accepts, either  gallian or maths online

Pliz help me...

Comment: The picture you posted has no definitions on it. Maybe you could clarify which assumptions are made in each text.

Comment: Ok, and as for Gallian's definition?

Comment: For  gallian  books  see page no 256

Comment: The difference is that Gallian for some reason allows subrings of integral domains which are not subrings when seen as unital rings.

Comment: @ Tobias okk  that  mean   Gallian  is Right

Comment: No, I think the the usual convention is like in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332206/prove-that-if-r-is-an-integral-domain-then-s-is-an-integral-domain).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but under the assumption of a set being a subring (under any of the two conventions), we still have that the set is an integral domain provided that the original ring is one, right? I don't see from where is OP's confusion arising.

Comment: @ Guido my  confusion  is that  this satement  is  true/false ?

Comment: @GuidoA. No, if we allow for example the set $\{0\}$ to be a subring (as Gallian does), then this is an example of a non-domain as a subring of any domain.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft totally missed that, thanks for clearing it up. Just to check, there are no other examples other than the trivial ring, correct?

Comment: @GuidoA. There can be others, since an integral domain is (usually) required to be unital, so any subring without unity will also be an example.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft oh, all right. I was assuming the same convention was imopsed for rings (and in particular integral domains) and subrings. Thanks for the clarification :)