# Let $w$ in $\Bbb C$ satisfy $w^2 \in \Bbb Z$, and define $Z(w) = \{n+mw | n,m \in \Bbb Z \}$, show $\Bbb Z(w)$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: Let $w$ in $\Bbb C$ satisfy $w^2 \in \Bbb Z$, and define $Z(w) = \{n+mw | n,m \in \Bbb Z \}$. I want to show that this is an integral domain.

Let $x,y = Z(w)$, say $x=(a+bw),y=(c+dw)$,

if $xy=ac+(ad+bc)w+bdw^2 = 0$, then

Equating components I get:
$ac+bdw^2=0$, and $ad+bc=0 \rightarrow ad=-bc$. Not sure how to proceed. Hints appreciated.

Comment: As a subring of the complex numbers it is automatically an integral domain. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332206/prove-that-if-r-is-an-integral-domain-then-s-is-an-integral-domain?rq=1).

Comment: You just have to show it is a subring of $\bf C$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde right, I have seen the proof that a subring of an integral domain is an integral domain. Should I delete the question then, or continue trying to prove it with the equations written?

Comment: The equations should show that it is a subring, see Bernard's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments,

$O \in \Bbb Z(w)$ take $n=0,m=0$,

$1 \in \Bbb Z(w)$ take $n=1, m=0$,

Take $n+mw \in \Bbb Z(w)$, $n'+m'w \in \Bbb Z (w)$,

then $(n+n')+(m+m')w \in \Bbb Z(w)$

$-n-mw \in \Bbb Z(w)$, and finally

$(nn'+mm'w^2)+(nm'+n'm)w \in \Bbb Z(w)$, therefore it is a subring of $\Bbb C$, and subrings of integral domains are integral domains.